# Combine multiple collections into a collection of structs with Enumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have multiple arrays of objects:
`A`, `B` ,`C`.
They all have the same length.

I want to write a function that "merges" each element of the arrays to single elements in the resuling array.

An example:

`(A[0] , B[0] , C[0]) => Result[0]`

There is `Enumerable.Join()`, but my data is not keyed.

Comment: [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))))? `Enumerable.Zip(A, B, C).Select(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `Zip`? E.g. we can combine items into a named tuple:

```
var result = A
  .Zip(B, (a, b) => (a, b))
  .Zip(C, (p, c) => (p.a, p.b, c));
```

E.g.

```
int[] A = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] B = { 4, 5, 6 };
int[] C = { 7, 8, 9 };

var result = A
  .Zip(B, (a, b) => (a, b))
  .Zip(C, (p, c) => (p.a, p.b, c));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
(3, 6, 9)
```

If you have *arbitrary* number of arrays you can join items into enumeration of arrays:

```
private static IEnumerable<T[]> ZipToArray<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources) {
  if (sources is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sources));

  var ens = sources
    .Select(source => source?.GetEnumerator())
    .ToArray();

  try {
    while (true) {
      foreach (var en in ens)
        if (!(en?.MoveNext() ?? true))
          yield break;

      yield return ens
        .Select(en => en is null ? default(T) : en.Current)
        .ToArray();
      }
  finally {
    foreach (var en in ens)
      en?.Dispose();
  }
}
```

E.g.

```
int[] A = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] B = { 4, 5, 6 };
int[] C = { 7, 8, 9 };

int[][] result = ZipToArray(A, B, C).ToArray();
```

Comment: A little bit inconvenient with different `T`s, but using multiple `Zip`s is no problem I guess.
Thank you!